# When to call MediaCodec:getOutputFormat()?

Tags: android, exception, android-mediacodec, native-code

For an audio codec, calling `MediaCodec::getOutputFormat()` throws an `IllegalStateException` on one device (not on another).

The Android docs says that such an exception is raised if the codec is not in the Configured or Executing states:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

On both devices, the call to `getOutputFormat` was after the codec was configured. There were also intervening calls to starting the codec, and retrieving its input and output buffers.

Does the call to `getOutputFormat` need to be immediately after the `configure()` call? The docs suggest that the call to `configure()` puts the codec in the Configured state, and the call to `start()` puts it in the Executing state. So it should be OK to put the call after the `start()`.

But in fact, a change was made in the boilerplate code in the docs, indicating that you get the `IllegalStateException` if you call `getOutputFormat()` just after `start()`:

https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/diff?spec=svn.platform--frameworks--base.e55d5e864b133df8ccf9f92ca4a5d3accb1dab5c&repo=platform--frameworks--base&name=jb-mr1-dev&r=b529e4c9ca8a6790162275ac2e481f768a6d585f&format=side&path=/media/java/android/media/MediaCodec.java&old_path=/media/java/android/media/MediaCodec.java&old=2ac3f2e285159300c62c797bb2123604773ccac7

So there's something else going on besides the codec state that triggers whether this exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only call `MediaCodec::getOutputFormat` after you get `MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` returned from `MediaCodec:: dequeueOutputBuffer`. It's not enough that it is in the executing state, the internal codec also needs to have produced the output `MediaFormat` object.

The example was fixed further soon after the `MediaCodec` API was made public, in https://android-review.googlesource.com/39100, but you're right that the documentation for the method itself also still needs to be fixed.

EDIT: Actually, the clause in the documentation for `MediaCodec::getOutputFormat` that says you can call it directly after `configure` was added in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d4023114e8cf7ec7db4d07958a303699b658f2c0%5E%21/ (which became part of the 5.0 release). Thefore you can probably do that successfully since 5.0, but not on earlier versions.

Comment: OK, is there a way to know, for an audio codec, what the output sample rate is, other than through getOutputFormat? I want to use that sample rate to construct an AudioTrack. Maybe I can just choose a suitable sample rate ...

Comment: It pretty much depends on the actual codec. For AAC, if you've got the `MediaFormat` object containing the codec specific data block (`csd-0`), you could parse that as well, but the sample rate should also be available in the `MediaFormat` directly. Also do note that the output samplerate or number of channels may be different from what the input `MediaFormat` object says - e.g. some AAC decoders decode mono AAC into stereo data.

Comment: The only really safe solution is to either construct the output `AudioTrack` only once you've got the `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` callback (or make your code flexible enough that you can remove and construct a new `AudioTrack` if necessary). Alternatively, just make a guess using the input `MediaFormat`, and do manual conversion of the audio data yourself (converting from stereo to mono or vice versa isn't too hard, but sample rate conversion is a bit harder). But the easiest is just to delay initializing the `AudioTrack`.

Comment: Yes, I've got the MediaFormat for the codec, but as you say, that's the input format. Am I guaranteed that I'll get the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED message, and within a reasonable time after starting the codec? If so, that would be the way to go.

Comment: My code now reads a sample and dequeues an output buffer until I get the `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` message. When I get the message, I create the AudioTrack and play the sample. Until then, I don't advance the extractor, so I don't drop any audio.

Comment: That sounds good. You don't need to be afraid of dropping any audio; there's two separate queues of packets for input and output. You can enqueue multiple input packets before you read the output, but if the output queue is full, you may not be able to enqueue any more input packets. You pretty much are guaranteed to get `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` within a reasonable time after starting the decoder (you will get it before you get the first decoded output buffer).

Comment: To be completely flexible, you may need to try to input more than one input buffer though - i.e. checking if `dequeueOutputBuffer` returns anything, if not, try to get another input buffer with `dequeueInputBuffer` and enqueue another input sample if needed. But I think most AAC decoders will output a buffer immediately once you give it one single packet.

Comment: Yes, that's how my code works. There's a loop that dequeues and queues an input buffer, then dequeues an output buffer. If there's no output buffer available, or there's an output buffer change or format change on a loop iteration, another input buffer will be dequeued and queued the next time around the loop.

Comment: I amended the answer with an explanation on why the documentation says you can do this directly after the `configure` call.